# Is OutputDebugString thread safe?

Tags: c++, windows

In my code I call these methods at various places to send diagnostic output to `DbgView`:

```
inline void dbg_info(std::string s) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "INFO:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << s << std::endl;
    OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
}

inline void dbg_err(std::string s) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "ERROR:" << std::this_thread::get_id() << ": " << s << std::endl;
    OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
}
```

Is the method `OutputDebugStringA()` thread safe or could it mix messages from multiple threads being output at the same time?

If not would it be sufficient and a good idea to create a static member variable of `std::mutex` and lock this in my two methods above?

Comment: [Are Debug Messages thread safe?](https://marc.info/?l=ms-atl&m=103430970637774&w=2) (I searched for `is OutputDebugStringA thread safe`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is thread safe. It uses a mutex and events. Implementation details [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/23776/mechanism-of-outputdebugstring).